# How does a swap function work with references?

Tags: c++, reference, swap

I want to swap two variables with a function. I create two functions **my_swap_f1** and **my_swap_f2**; **my_swap_f2** works perfectly but **my_swap_f1** throws 2 errors (commented out below).

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int my_swap_f1(int &a,int &b){

    int *temp;
    temp=&a;
    //&a=&b;   //throw error
    //&b=temp;    //throw error
}

int my_swap_f2(int *a,int *b){
    //works perfectly
    int temp;
    temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}

int main(){
    int a=10;
    int b=20;
    int temp=0;
    cout<<"Before Swap"<<endl;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<b<<endl;

    my_swap_f1(a,b); //send value as perameter
    //my_swap_f2(&a,&b); //send address as perameter
    cout<<"After Swap"<<endl;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<b<<endl;
}
```

Question: Why are errors thrown in `my_swap_f1` and what should I do if I want to swap with `my_swap_f1`?

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2176813), never use it.

Comment: can u explain why its a bad practice?? @tambre

Comment: `&a=&b;` ->`a=b;` and `&b=temp;` -> `b=*temp;` It looks like you do not understand how to use reference variables in C++, you should review that. (Also there is no need for `int* temp` either)

Comment: Try clicking on the link, to learn why it's bad practice.

Answer (score 5):

One of the main reasons to implement swap with references instead of pointers is to avoid all that `*` and `&` in the code:

```
int my_swap_f1(int &a,int &b){
    int temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;             // a/b refer to the parameters that were passed
    b = temp;          // modifying a reference is the same as modifiying the original
}
```

That line:

```
&a = &b;
```

cannot work, because `&a` (the address of `a`) is a rvalue. A rvalue is, sloppy speaking, something that you cannot assign to, it can only appear on the right side of an assignment. If it worked it would mean something like: "Take the address of `a` and set it to the address of `b`", but of course you cannot change the address of an object like that.

Comment: "assing" -> "assign"

Comment: @MillieSmith thx fixed. btw typos like that you can also fix by yourself. Or cant you edit answers?

Comment: I just feel like I'm stepping on people's toes when I make a one-character edit for spelling. I guess I would have done it for someone with less rep.

Comment: @MillieSmith would be completely fine with me. And imho rep is overrated, I could have made all my rep on java and still my c++ answers would look like I know what I am talking about (i didnt and still sometimes I dont know what I am talking about ;). Btw you will get a notification if someone edits your posts so you always have to chance to roll it back

Comment: True. I'll edit them from now on and see if I get pushback. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `my_swap_f1` and `my_swap_f2` is that `my_swap_f2` declares its arguments to be *pointer* types, while `my_swap_f1` declares its arguments to be *reference* types. References work differently from pointers in C++, and you are attempting to use references incorrectly in `my_swap_f1`.

In C++ a reference type is an **immutable** pointer-like handle, which points to only one instance of the referred-to type and can never be reassigned. It is treated like a *value* of the referenced type in most expressions, meaning that you can access the referred-to instance "directly" without dereferencing anything. Thus, if you declare a reference variable `int &a`, the reference `a` points to exactly one `int`, and you can access that `int`'s value by just writing `a`, such as in the assignment `int temp = a` (note that `temp` is just an `int`, not a reference). There's no need to write `&a`, and doing so will in fact take the address of the `int` that `a` refers to (giving you a pointer-to-`int`), because the "address of" operator (`&`) will be applied directly to the `int` value.

This will make more sense if you write your parameter declarations with the "pointer modifier" next to the *type name* rather than the variable name:

```
//This function's parameters are two pointers
int my_swap_f2(int* a, int* b);

//This function's parameters are two references
int my_swap_f1(int& a, int& b);
```

Then, when implementing `my_swap_f1`, you can change the `int` value that `a` refers to by assigning to `a` directly, because `a` is a "reference to `int`." The correct version of your function would be:

```
void my_swap_f1(int& a, int& b) {
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Note that in line 3, the assignment overwrites the `int` that `a` refers to with the value of the `int` that `b` refers to. The references themselves cannot be changed, so there is no need to add any extra symbols (like `&`) to indicate the referred-to value rather than the reference itself. (Also, I changed the function return type to `void`, since your code  does not actually return a value from the function, and it doesn't need to).

Comment: `&a` takes the address of the variable designated by `a`. There is no such thing as "address of a reference".  Many people (including me) dislike the "references are immutable pointers" pedagogy, we feel it causes more confusion than it solves. You certainly could talk about the address of an immutable pointer, but there is no address of a reference.

Comment: @M.M, yes, you're right, I should have double-checked what `&a` did before posting. I have never tried to take the address of a reference before (why would you?) so I didn't know about this edge case. I fixed my answer to be more accurate.

Comment: I would change "points to" to "refers to" in the last section. I mean do as you like, but as you started editing it already I thought I mention it...

Comment: @tobi303 I explained it that way because the OP seemed to understand  pointers but not references, so I thought comparing them to pointers would make sense. But you're right, it's unsafe to assume that references are pointers because that's an implementation detail, so I changed my wording.

Comment: Should "overwrites the int that a refers to" be "changes the value of the int that a refers to" instead?